# My 2008 Honda Accord, dies once parked. (3 times)

Tags: honda, troubleshooting

My girlfriends vehicle has recently been giving me trouble. I regularly maintenance the vehicle. We've had it for 4 years. Been very great. 
Three times after we/she drives her car, nothing seemingly wrong, the car dies after we get to a destination. Once placed in park and the key is removed. And sometimes not until you've locked it with the fob. 
Here is the kicker... After 6-8 hours... It returns to life...
Can anyone please help me troubleshooting, or if this has happened to you... You'll be saving my life .. (not literally)

Current situation... Son has a soccer game in the morning... I will be taking..
However we just went grocery shopping and used her car. I then proceeded to place my truck keys in her console. Went inside, locked the doors and no we are locked out of her car because it has died... 
May come down to a broken window.

Comment: is the battery dying when you try to start it does it takes long and turn slowly when cranking ? If you have a multimeter measure the battery voltage when it's dead after removing the plus connector and see.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!